# comboViewer.getSelection() returning null in eclipse rcp

Tags: eclipse-rcp

i have created a `ComboViewer` named `comboViewer` in a `TitleAreaDialog` box.
Viewer is populated by various categories which are defined in `TreeViewer`.

but a NullPointerException is thrown at the following line:

```
ISelection categorySelection = comboViewer.getSelection();
```

Why is it so and what will be the fix?

Comment: Where does that line of code live?  We'll need to see some more code.  If you're calling `comboViewer.getSelection()` after the dialog box has been dismissed, for instance, that's not going to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this using this 'pattern', i.e. when setting up your dialog:

```
  final ISelection selection = new ISelection[1];

  Dialog diag = new Dialog(shell) {
    // createDialogArea()
    // remember your comboViewer as field


    @Override
    protected void okPressed() {
      selection[0] = comboViewer.getSelection();
      super.okPressed();
    }
  };
```

(Use TitleAreaDialog instead of Dialog for your case.)

I.e. override the okPressed method of the dialog. If the user has made a selection, then presses OK, selection[0] will contain the selection.

Comment: hey,  thanks for the help but still the problem persists. Is there any other way out?

Comment: comboViewer.getSelection() is called inside okPressed().